# Uncaught TypeError scroll effect navigation?

Tags: jquery, html

I got the problem
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined .

how about href="index.html#section2"?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
scrollEffect();
 });


function scrollEffect() {
    $('#nav-link a').click(function(){
         $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
    });
}


<nav id="top-header-wrapper">
    <div id="nav-link">
        <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section2">about</a>
        <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section3">portfolio</a>
        <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section4">contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is it possible that your `href` isn't visible? `.offset` doesn't return anything if the element isn't visible. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bLm3M/. Do your `href`s have `#` in them? In any case, showing HTML/CSS is always more helpful.

Comment: how about href="index.html#section2"?

<nav id="top-header-wrapper">
  <div id="nav-link">
   <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section2">about</a>
   <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section3">portfolio</a>
   <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section4">contact</a>
  </div>
 </nav>